# Hiding WordPress sidebar if on phone only, not iPad, tablet, etc…

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I have Google AdSense on my site’s my sidebar but it looks horrible on a mobile phone. The goal is to remove the sidebar if it’s viewed on a mobile device, but keep it everywhere else. So if it’s on a mobile device hide it, but desktop and tablets show it.

If have found this:

```
if (wp_is_mobile()) {
    // hide sidebar
} else {
    dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); 
}
```

Which works, but obviously hides it on all mobile devices including tablets. Is there another function perhaps that is just for phone size screens? I have tried to use media queries in the css but to no avail!

Comment: `I have tried to use media queries in the css but to no avail!` Why? What did you try? What happened?

Comment: use css media queries. Without html and css code we can't help you.

Comment: I will repeat the previous comment to stress that it's the best solution. Use media queries. Just use this:  [Css Tricks Link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score 0):

this done the trick:

```
function wp_on_phone() {
   if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])

       // bail out, if iPad
       && false !== strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPad')
   ) 
      return false;
   return wp_is_mobile();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS media queries. here is an example

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {

.sidebar-1{display:none;}

}